# Applications for OS X to manage Linux servers over SSH

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, documentation

Are there any applications for OS X to handle these things in SSH for a Linux server?

- Store list of configuration files paths (`/etc/apache2` etc. to remind where they are all located)
- Store list of handy commands (`nano /etc/php/apache2/php.ini`)
- Store list of server properties (hardware, location etc.)

How do other administrators manage these servers properly?

Comment: For your second task, use Bash aliases: `alias phpini='nano /etc/php/apache2/php.ini'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Store list of configuration files paths

After working with systems for a while, you simply know the paths. You **know** global settings are most likely to be in `/etc/<applicationname>`, you **know** your log files are in `/var/log`, you **know** you live in `/home/mike`.
These paths will get second nature to you. **And they better should.**

### Store list of handy commands

Go over to [commandlinefu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/browse) and create a list of your favorites.
Also, once you know your paths, you might not even need to write down stuff like your example.

You know you like `nano` for editing, you know you want to edit the PHP settings for Apache, so it's `nano /etc/php/apache/php.conf` or something like that. But that **isn't** the right path, is it? So use tab-completion to get the real one:

```
nano /etc/php/apa<tab>
nano /etc/php/apache2/php<tab>
nano /etc/php/apache2/php.ini
```

And there we go.

### Store list of server properties (hardware, location etc.)

Do it however you like it. Create a Wiki. A plaintext file if you like that better. Just do it.
Also, try to learn how to extract that information from a machine if you need to get it quickly. A quick `lspci` or `ip a` or `route -n` or `cat /etc/*-release` or `uname -a` can be all you really need at times.

### Monitoring Tools

In my opinion, the go-to monitoring tool is [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/). It's weird to set up, but there are quite a few tutorials on the web. It can monitor all the metrics you noted in your comments (and many more):
[image: CPU]
[image: Memory]
[image: Disk]

Comment: Thanks alot, I really appreaciate your answer. One more question, what are some default server administration tools, prefer webbased ones, like monitor CPU usage, memory usage, disk usage etc. Thanks alot man!

Comment: I updated my answer to address your question regarding monitoring :)

Answer (score 1):

1) store list of configuration files paths:

for diverse machines with changes that are machine-specific: whenever you change a file, ALWAYS store a version and your changes using rcs tools:

```
ci -l httpd.conf
```

A `find / -type f -name \*,v` gives you all changed config files. Works for every platform with rcs.

For more than just 2 hosts with similar changes, like shared config files with host-specific differences like nodename:

http://oss.oracle.com/projects/cvsman/

this is really worth every minute you spend on it - payoff comes in spades. Needs a solid SOP for every admin to follow, and a bit of education/changed mindset.

2) store list of handy commands:

team wiki. gist on github. Tiddlywiki in a SCM. Whatever works for you. I use text files that live in a CVS repository.

3) store list of server properties

seen everything, from notes on the back of burger wrappers to paid-for inventory database systems. Those two are quite nice, used them both:

http://racktables.org/

http://www.chrismandery.de/phpequimon/